# C/C++ Preprocessor #include syntax. Whitespace mandatory?

Tags: c-preprocessor

In some code from others I came across the notation:

```
#include"file.h"
```

And I wondered, I always write include syntaxes with a space between the directive and the path/file like:

```
#include "file.h"
```

So I searched for the `#include` syntax, but could not find a difinitive answer. As it only shows how it is used but I could not find the exact syntax.

Resource used: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html#Include-Syntax

Is there even a spec written about how the syntax should be? Or is the first one (without the whitespace) invalid syntax but accepted through pre-compiler extensions?

(Also works on MSVC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is allowed to have `#include<header>` and `#include"header"`, with no whitespace character after `include`, although one may argue that this makes it slightly harder to read.

The grammar for `#include` is, cut down to only show the relevant bits:

```
# include pp-tokens new-line

pp-tokens: preprocessing-token

preprocessing-token: header-name

header-name: < h-char-sequence >
             " q-char-sequence "
```

(spaces in the above is only part of the grammar syntax, bold text is literal)

Furthermore:

> Preprocessing tokens **can** be separated by *white space*; this consists of
>   comments (described later), or *white-space characters* (space,
>   horizontal tab, new-line, vertical tab, and form-feed), or both.

This is from the [C99 draft standard document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (my emphasis on "can").

I'm not a C++ programmer, but I imagine that C++ is following the same grammar rules on this point.